# How to share data across multiple instances with a common parent?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I have the following code

```
//parent class
class Parent {
 private Object data;
 Parent (Object data){
  this.data=data;
 }
 method1(){}
 ...
 methodN(){}
}
//wrapper class
class Wrapper extends Parent {
 Wrapper(Object object){
   super(object)
  }
 class Son1{
  //do something
 }
 class SonN {
  //do something
 }
}
```

Parent has useful methods for their sons, the wrapper is meant to create only one instance of the Parent in order to give access to the inner classes the Parent's methods and data

All works fine, however, the wrapper became huge due to all the sons.

I'm figuring out how to move each son to its own class (In a separate file) without impact the existing code

what I did so far is to make each son to extend directly from Parent and passing the data to the parent through the constructor

```
class SonN extends Parent{
  SonN(Object object){
  super(object)
  }
}
```

it works, but I see a downside, each check that gets created will have its own instance of  Parent

I'm not really worried about the extra memory used, I think it won't make any notorious difference in the software but I have some questions

- Is there a design pattern for this cases?
- If the number of sons will continue growing up, would it be better to remain with the original design?
- is there a better way to share the methods to the sons keeping the memory used low?

**Note**

there are multiple instances of wrapper at the same time pointing to different objects what limits the usage of static variables

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the context but i think perhaps it is enough to implement the principal **composition over inheritance**, in which you create a single instance of Parent and pass it to all the sons, which implement a common interface. Wrapper may be no longer necessary. You can add new type of Son anytime, you also dont have a tight coupling between the Parent and Sons so they can vary independently:

```
class SonN implements SonInterface {
   private Parent parent;
   SonN(Parent parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also not sure about your context but let me try to answer as understood.

First of all the parent son relationship is not very subtle. Parent child hierarchy should always **capture the essence of parent-child**. One should never extends just to use the parent method. Therefore it is always advisable to **prefer the composition over inheritance**, unless the use case captures the essence.

Second it not very clear how the son's use data. Will they alter it, or will it be read only. **I mean if the data is immutable**, design choice should consider these as well.

Moving towards your approach, with the assumption of data being immutable.

**First Approach**- Nested inner class is created either to encapsulate the data and have inner class access to private fields, or, creating helper class for the enclosing class. In your case if you want access to the parents class methods, you can prefer composition, and avoid the wrapper class.
So you can pass same parent to all the sons.

```
public class Parent {
    public void method(){
    }
}

public class Son {
    private Parent parent;
    public Son(Parent parent){
        this.parent= parent;
    }

}
```

**Second Approach**-As discussed earlier your case is appropriate for composition.